# New column with non-zero values from either of two columns, NA or error if multiple non-zero values

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, case

I'm working with R and I have a data frame with two columns with values that most of the time are zeros. Now, I want to create a new column (of the same length as the original two columns) that contains either a non-zero value from either one of the two columns or a zero. And if by any chance (it shouldn't happen but just to be sure) both columns have a non-zero entry for a certain row, I want to get the text "error" as  an entry in the new column).

I've tried this:

```r
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    newcolumn = case_when(
      column1 !=0 ~ column1,
      column2 !=0 ~ column2,
      (column1 == 0 & column2 == 0) ~ 0,
      (column1 != 0 & column2 != 0) ~ "error"
    )
  )
```

For some reason, R doesn't like that I want it to return "error" or any other character. Is there a way to fix this? (there are some NAs in the columns but I don't think it depends on that since R will accept the code above if instead of "error" I want it to return a numeric)

---

PS: Of course, I'm open to more elegant ways of doing this.

Comment: Every possible value in a `case_when` must be the same class, this clearly is confounding `numeric` with `character` (and possibly whatever `column1` and `column2` are). For example, `case_when(T~1, F~"A")` errors whereas `case_when(T~"1", F~"A")` does not.

Comment: This code is buggy, no question. What is it you want to be able to do with the `newcolumn` in the end? Should it be integer/numeric? Do you need to differentiate between `NA` (from before the `case_when`) with some error condition? What do you need to happen when you find the condition that leads to your `"error"`?

Comment: I want the new column to be numeric, and yes, I would like to differentiate the two. If the condition that leads to my "error" is met I want to get notified or, better, the code to stop and tell me there has been an error. Thanks @r2evans !

Comment: Well, we can't do something like `case_when(..., (...) ~ stop("oops"))`, so I wonder if you can use a sentinel `numeric` value to indicate a problem. It's best to pick a value that absolutely cannot exist in your real data, examples might include `NA` (I think this is possible in real data, so not this); `NaN`; `-1` (if your real data is non-negative); or perhaps the max possible value plus 1000 or similar. The only catch to all of this is that when you inject a value like that to indicate an error, you must catch (and `stop(.)`?) immediately, not leaving it in the results.

Comment: Another option (that I really don't like ... but it can work): return strings for all possible results, such as `column2 != 0 ~ as.character(column2)`; this allows you to end with `... ~ "error"`. _Then_, react to the presence of `"error"` in your data, and filter those rows out. _Then_ convert your strings to `numeric` with `mutate(newcolumn=as.numeric(newcolumn))`, recognizing that you _might_ need to use `suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))` if it is at all noisy in ways you expect.

Comment: Maybe I can use 99999 instead of "error" and if there is an instance of that I can put NA everywhere. That should work, though not very elegant.

Comment: I use databases with sentinel values like that, and it is _really frustrating_ when a sentinel value is unadvertised and allowed to be consumed as "real data". For instance, one data-processor (not under my control) uses a sentinel value of `0` (for an internal variable that is unlikely to be 0) for when a specific error condition is met. Unfortunately, they don't fix the problem, don't document the sentinel value, and so when I consume it the `0` is just a number among many other numbers; `mean(c(98,0,99))` is a legitimate operation. **Bottom line**: fix it before returning data to the users.